# How to ensure that only one particular Cocoa App will invoke another Cocoa app using App Sandboxing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox

My One Cocoa app, say X, will launch another Cocoa app say Y and will talk together through socket connection. I am using Asynch Socket (https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) library to communicate between the two app.  Here app X, search for service name of App Y and communicate together.

I want to ensure, that only app-X will communicate to app-Y and someway, if any other app get the service name will not be able to communicate to Y.

So is there any idea to accomplish the same. I don't want to use SSL/TLS mechanism supported by the library (startTLS method).

I have come to know that app sandbox provided by the OS X can be helpful to do so. But I am not sure what to add in the entitlement plist to achieve my purpose.

Any idea/solution ?